# How to add/embed SQL Script/snippet to blogger ?

Tags: blogs, blogger

How can i embed sql scripts in blogger. When i add the script to blogger it is taking as plain text. How can i retain sql color coding when i add the code in blogger?

Ex: SELECT * FROM sys.sysdatabases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution ... Follow the steps here. It worked for me.

http://geektalkin.blogspot.com/2009/11/embed-code-syntax-highlighting-in-blog.html